# PHP doesn't call a jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to replace the text from the *div id="texto"* but it isn't working.

The idea I had in mind was that when I click the button, *pag1()* function would replace the text from *"texto"* with the *var pag1* from *application.js*.

It doesn't do anything at all, which is confusing.

Here are both files:

**index.php**

```
<html>    
    <head>
        <!-- Meta -->
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="Luis, Almerich, De Haro, Luis Almerich, Almerich de Haro, Estudihac, Siroppe, Publicidad, CEU, Valencia" lang="es" />
        <meta name="description" content="Luis Almerich de Haro, publicista." />
        <meta name="author" content="Abraham Menéndez" />
        <!-- UTF-8, mime -->
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
        <!-- Letra para texto común, cambiar por Garamond. -->
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <!-- Letra para textbox del nombre. -->
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Special+Elite' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <!-- Se adapta, no se puede aumentar ni disminuir -->
        <meta name='viewport' content='user-scalable=0'>
        <!-- jQuery 2 -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!-- CSS -->
        <link href="styles.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <!-- Titulo de la página -->
        <title> Página de Luis </title>

        <!-- Init -->
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                application_init();
            });   
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="content">
                <form action="">
                    <div id="texto">
                        Cargando...
                        <NOSCRIPT>
                            Javascript desactivado.
                        </NOSCRIPT>
                        <input type="button" value="This is a button" onclick="pag1();"/>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

**application.js**

```
var p1 = "<p>Esto es la página 1.</p>";
var p2 = "<p>Esto es la página 2.</p>";
var p3 = "<p>Esto es la página 3.</p>";

/* Init.*/
function application_init() {
    "use strict";
    window.alert("It's working!");
}

function pag1() {
    "use strict";
    document.getElementById("texto").html(p1);
}
```

**Here is the "live web version":**

```
<http://www.luisalmerich.com>
```

Comment: As a side note, PHP and JavaScript will never interact directly. The PHP is executed on the server. The result (typically HTML but it could also be JavaScript, a JPEG or any other file type) is sent to the browser. The browser then executes the JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **[`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)** for setting html content in javascript

```
function pag1() {
  "use strict";
  document.getElementById("texto").innerHTML = p1;
}
```

You can use **[`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)** for jQuery object

```
function pag1() {
  "use strict";
  $("#texto").html(p1);
}
```

Comment: Well that was a dumb mistake. Thank you very much, Pranav.

Comment: @anonymous : glad to help